# How to use my Package in Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, composer-php, laravel-5

I have a question related to Package for Laravel 5. I am creating one package and tried to use that. package successfully created and using composer i can also get that in New Laravel setup , issue is that when i tried to use that it's says class not found. Here's my composer.json and Steps that i followed:

for e.g. `my username = git_test and packagename = mypackage`

***My Package Structure :***

> **git_test > mypackage > src

***My composer.json file***

```
{
    "name": "git_test/mypackage",
    "description": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "keywords": ["laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "XXXXXXX",
            "email": "XXXXXX@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "illuminate/support": "5.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "git_test\\mypackage\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

***Here's my src/myclass.php***

```
namespace git_test\mypackage;

class myclass {
    function test(){ echo "This is Test"; }
}
```

Now i am going to use this in my new laravel project so i add package in my directory composer and try to use the `myclass` in my HomeController

***HomeController Code***

```
use git_test\mypackage\myclass  as TaskClass;

class HomeController extends Controller {

   public function index()
    {
            $atTaskObj = new TaskClass('');
    }
```

I got the error like `"git_test\mypackage\myclass" Not Found`. where i am doing wrong? any suggestion please.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Any help can really appreciate !!

Comment: make sure your `myclass` is working correctly. Write a test for it. Try `php artisan dump-autoload` and `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score -1):

PSR-4 paths have to end with `\\`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "git_test\\mypackage\\": "src/"
    }
},
```